# Rewrite from-address of all outgoing e-mail from a server using Postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I want `postfix` to rewrite the from address of all this server's outgoing e-mail. Anyone know how could I accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at alterMIME http://www.pldaniels.com/altermime/

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/118692-postfix-sender-address-rewriting.html

Comment: Thank you Khaled that worked! Can you post an answer so I could mark it as answered? More so for others who might have the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is described in http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic

It states to use the `smtp_generic_maps` to rewrite the outgoing addresses (in header **and** envelope!). The example given there uses the `hash` lookup table for rewriting. But you are - as usual in Postfix - able to use the `regex` or `pcre` lookup table for rewriting. Which could rewrite like

```
/.*/    masqueraded@example.com
```

This approach even enables you to rewrite addresses only under some special conditions that you can write as regular expressions.

Comment: The example is not that good: in my test it can modify the recipient address too! Something like `/.*@LocalDomain/` should work better.